# Is it possible to get a list element based on a combination of multiple sub-list values?

Tags: json, shell, select, jq

I have a data structure provided to me (by kubectl) in the following format relating to some custom resource definitions in a cluster. I want to use `jq` or similar to return `.items[x].metadata.name` when that list element's `.status.conditions` list has a condition of `.type == "Ready"` and `.status == "False"`.

The 'business case' is "Get any custom resources that are not yet ready."

I get the feeling that the structure of the data is making this difficult, but am wondering if it is possible to do with `jq` at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```json
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [
        {
            "metadata": {
                "name": "return-me"
            },
            "spec": {
                "region": "ap-southeast-2"
            },
            "status": {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "message": "Some Condition A",
                        "reason": "Supported",
                        "status": "True",
                        "type": "IsSupported"
                    },
                    {
                        "message": "Some Condition B",
                        "reason": "Shared",
                        "status": "True",
                        "type": "IsShared"
                    },
                    {
                        "message": "Some Condition C",
                        "reason": "Accepted",
                        "status": "False",
                        "type": "IsAccepted"
                    },
                    {
                        "status": "True",
                        "type": "OthersReady"
                    },
                    {
                        "status": "False",
                        "type": "Ready"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "metadata": {
                "name": "dont-return-me"
            },
            "spec": {
                "region": "ap-northeast-1"
            },
            "status": {
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "message": "Some Condition A",
                        "reason": "Supported",
                        "status": "True",
                        "type": "IsSupported"
                    },
                    {
                        "message": "Some Condition B",
                        "reason": "Shared",
                        "status": "True",
                        "type": "IsShared"
                    },
                    {
                        "message": "Some Condition C",
                        "reason": "Accepted",
                        "status": "False",
                        "type": "IsAccepted"
                    },
                    {
                        "status": "True",
                        "type": "OthersReady"
                    },
                    {
                        "status": "True",
                        "type": "Ready"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
    ],
    "kind": "List",
    "metadata": {
        "resourceVersion": "",
        "selfLink": ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your input, the filter

```
.items[]
| select( any(.status.conditions[];  .type == "Ready" and .status == "False") )
| .metadata.name
```

returns

```
"return-me"
```

... which seems hopeful :-)

#### Note

People familiar with SQL's `select` should note that jq's `select` selects elements from its input stream, and is thus quite different from SQL's select, which is used to select "fields" from each "record" in a table.